# openldap auththentication php5 - comparing the password

Tags: php, openldap

I'm trying to authenticate againest an ldap server I've created. The user password is stored within ldap as sha hash. However when I try accessing the userPassword attribute it doesn't exist. I have to login as the manager. Am assuming this isn't a very good idea on a production server. is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to return the password field. You may simply authenticate against the ldap server with given credentials.

see this example (reference here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php)

```
<?php

$user = 'bob';
$password = 'zhlob';
$host = 'myldap';
$domain = 'mydomain.ex';
$basedn = 'dc=mydomain,dc=ex';
$group = 'SomeGroup';

$ad = ldap_connect("ldap://{$host}.{$domain}") or die('Could not connect to LDAP server.');
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
@ldap_bind($ad, "{$user}@{$domain}", $password) or die('Could not bind to AD.');
$userdn = getDN($ad, $user, $basedn);
if (checkGroupEx($ad, $userdn, getDN($ad, $group, $basedn))) {
//if (checkGroup($ad, $userdn, getDN($ad, $group, $basedn))) {
    echo "You're authorized as ".getCN($userdn);
} else {
    echo 'Authorization failed';
}
ldap_unbind($ad);
?>
```